# SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >=

Tags: sql

When i run the Below Query it shows error as follow : **"SQL Server Subquery returned more than 1 value. the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"**

```
SELECT TOP(1) * 
FROM   E_MASTER 
WHERE  STATUSTYPE <> 'D' 
       AND EMPID = 'EMP459788' 
       AND DEPTNO IN (SELECT DEPTNO 
                      FROM   SERVICE_MASTER 
                      WHERE  EMPNAME = '......') 
       AND ( DESG_CODE BETWEEN (SELECT S_DESG_CODE 
                                FROM   SERVICE_MASTER) AND (SELECT E_DESG_CODE 
                                                            FROM 
                               SERVICE_MASTER) )
```

Comment: At a guess `SELECT E_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER` or `SELECT S_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER` is returning more than one value.

Comment: First: The error message says what is the problem with your query. Read and understand it! Second: SO is not a debugging service! Otherwise: All subqueris used in the SELECT list or as a value participating in comparsion should return one (or none) record with exactly one column.

Comment: Check if `SELECT S_DESG_CODE FROM   SERVICE_MASTER` or `SELECT E_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER` is returning more than one value

Answer (score 0):

Let's see... The most probable culprint is the "between" clause. Try to see what that subqueries are returning.

```
(SELECT S_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER) AND
(SELECT E_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER)
```

You can change your logic to allow that subqueries to return more that one row or make then return just one depending on your requirements.

It's impossible to tell for sure without knowing how your relational diagram.
But you can try to remove that between from the where clause and relate SERVICE_MASTER with itself using a join.

```
SELECT S_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER sm0
join SERVICE_MASTER sm1 on sm1.E_DESG_CODE <= sm0.DESG_CODE
join SERVICE_MASTER sm2 on sm2.S_DESG_CODE >= sm0.DESG_CODE
```

If you cannot just use the where to filter for each row. (Note your actual query logic is equivalent to the snipet above and after writing it I'm not sure if it's what you really want)

```
SELECT S_DESG_CODE FROM SERVICE_MASTER
where E_DESG_CODE <= DESG_CODE and S_DESG_CODE >= DESG_CODE
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Pred: Well, the unasked :-) question seems to be "What am I doing wrong?" and the answer is "The subqueries in your BETWEEN clause must not return more than one value. Change this so they return one row only or change your logic to allow for multiple checks." This *is* an answer in my opinion.

Comment: The post *after* edit is an answer, basic hints without explanation is just a comment (the original post) in my opinion